# Maximum coverage of JUnit Test case

Tags: java, junit

Tests should have good coverage of the types of exceptions and errors that this class can throw, and it should have good coverage of the defective statements in the constructor method for CalculatePrimesMother.

The method for which three Junit test case needed is as below:

```
public CalculatePrimesMother(int numWorkers, int queueLength, int maxPrime,
            boolean verbose) {

        this.numWorkers = numWorkers;

        // Instantiate 3 queues, for thread-safe communication with workers
        Candidate = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(queueLength);
        Prime = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(queueLength);
        Composite = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(queueLength);

        this.maxPrime = maxPrime;
        this.sqrtMaxPrime = (int) Math.sqrt(maxPrime);
        primeFactors = new int[sqrtMaxPrime];
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }
```

I tried and created some test case but not able to get full coverage can anyone help me?

```
public class CalculatePrimesMotherTest extends TestCase {

    public CalculatePrimesMotherTest(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    private CalculatePrimesMother testMother;

    @Test
    public final void testCalculatePrimesMotherNegativequeueLength() {
        try {
            testMother = new CalculatePrimesMother(4, -12, 908, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    @Test
    public final void testCalculatePrimesMotherMinusOne() {
        try {
            testMother = new CalculatePrimesMother(8, 12, 0, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have no branches in your constructor so simply calling new CalculatePrimesMother once would give you full coverage of the constructor method. What tool are you using to calculate coverage? Which lines are claimed to be not-covered by this tool?

Comment: If you are not getting full coverage, it has to be because an exception is thrown and you are catching it in the test. That is something you should not do. The idea is to let jUnit catch all the exceptions thrown in your code so that it can detect if the test has failed or not.

Answer (score 1):

What coverage do you get?  There are no if tests in your ctor, so a single call should exercise all the code that I see.

You're writing too much code.  The setUp and tearDown and test constructor methods are all unnecessary.  Remove them.

You don't need the try/catch blocks in the other tests.  Remove those, too.  You want an exception to trigger a test failure.  Catching will hide the error.

Comment: I want to check all possible scenario for that method. so all possible error or exception condition should be there.

Comment: You did.  I see no checked exceptions being thrown.  What makes you think you don't have 100% coverage?  Is there a tool giving you a metric, or just you imagining that you're missing something?

Comment: @user2886707 That is not what you are doing. You are telling jUnit that if there is an exception, he should neglect it! If you want to take into account all possible exception, you should use the “expected“ annotation. Check this out http://www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html

Comment: Right, and if you don't expect an exception you want to be told that there's a failure.  That's why you don't catch.

Comment: @duffymo No I am using tool for checking it. and can you suggest me possible testcases for given method

Comment: @user2886707 I don't know how you are testing this, but I get 100% coverage in my computer.

Comment: Just one test is sufficient for coverage.  I think you've written some useless tests, because you don't assert anything.  You're too concerned about something that doesn't matter and not concerned enough about something that does.